# How do I remove soft block from USB using terminal command

Tags: usb, rfkill

from my

```
sudo rfkill list
i2400m usb.1 1.4 1.0 wiMAX
   Soft blocked yes
   Hard blocked no
```

Im trying to download ubuntu 20.04 from another laptop using a tethered port.

Comment: Try `sudo rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: I get> { 1059.557678} i2400m_usb 1-1.4;1.0: 'RF Control' (0x4602) command failed: -84 - invalid state (3)